# Как увеличить размер отображаемой картинки в CoverView

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения, controls

Я использую [CoverView](https://ghost1372.github.io/handycontrol/extend_controls/coverView/) из HandyControls пакета для просмотра фотографий.
Не получается увеличить панель для отображения картинки. Ширина этой панели по ширине окна, а вот высоту увеличить не получается.

Вот что у меня есть сейчас:

```
<Grid>
    <hc:CoverView VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding ImagePaths}">
        <hc:CoverView.ItemHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </hc:CoverView.ItemHeaderTemplate>
        <hc:CoverView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Margin="1" Background="#FF3A3A3A">
                    <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </hc:CoverView.ItemTemplate>
    </hc:CoverView>
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке изменить размер картинки, она просто обрезается:

```
<Grid>
    <hc:CoverView VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding ImagePaths}">
        <hc:CoverView.ItemHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </hc:CoverView.ItemHeaderTemplate>
        <hc:CoverView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Margin="1" Background="#FF3A3A3A">
                    <Image Width="1000" Height="1000" Source="{Binding}"/>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </hc:CoverView.ItemTemplate>
    </hc:CoverView>
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полный скрин окна:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `При попытке изменить размер картинки, она просто обрезается` - а должна как? Я просто смотрю на это и не понимаю, как в такое небольшое пространство вы пытаетесь запихнуть такое большое изображение.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Вот в этом и вопрос, как увеличить это пространство?

Comment: Ну у вас под размер окна все и так растянуто, делайте не знаю, окно больше) Либо прибегайте к хитростям, скрывайте верхние и нижние блоки (как в вашем контроле делать без понятия, если стандартно, то просто триггер на размер окна), ну или делайте при клике "попап" окно, которое будет поверх всего показывать картинку на черном фоне, вот вам стандартные механизмы. А растягивание, ну куда вы тут растянуть то собрались? Ну сделаете вы для картинки больше место, а верх и низ куда пойдет? За пределы экрана? Ну, такое себе)

Comment: <Border Margin="10" Height="600" - например так в примере на сайте написано. Свойства есть ItemContentHeight по умолчанию - 300

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Растягивать есть куда, вот только вопрос как это сделать.

Comment: @Виктор Спасибо, получилось